# using sets in a case end command

Tags: mysql, select, set, case

I have a table T with a field called county. I want to do something like

```
select (CASE
              WHEN T.county IN ('Ana', 'Beba', 'Ceca') THEN 'Rural'
              WHEN T.county IN ('Bob', 'Mob', 'Cob') THEN 'Urban'
        END) 'County Group'
```

the possible values for county are 'Ana', 'Beba', 'Ceca', 'Bob', 'Mob', 'Cob'

how can this be done? I am trying to use ('Ana', 'Beba', 'Ceca') and ('Bob', 'Mob', 'Cob') as sets

Thanks
Jose

Comment: And what problem do you have with your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine, although I would write it as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN T.county IN ('Ana', 'Beba', 'Ceca')
             THEN 'Rural'
             WHEN T.county IN ('Bob', 'Mob', 'Cob') 
             THEN 'Urban'
        END) as CountyGroup
FROM T;
```

Advice:  Don't use single quotes for column names.  You will probably have a problem in the future.